# Which could be a good structure for assimp material property in Java?

Tags: java, c++, c, enums, assimp

I am doing a port of Assimp to Java [here](https://github.com/elect86/jAssimp)

I am dealing now with materials.. Assimp have a quite complicate structure imho (and they themselves also say it: *it's an ugly macro for historical reasons, don't ask*)

These are the relevant C classes:

- [MaterialSystem.cpp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/code/MaterialSystem.cpp)
- [MaterialSystem.h](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/code/MaterialSystem.h)
- [material.inl](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/include/assimp/material.inl)
- [material.h](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/include/assimp/material.h)

In the [docs](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/materials.html), you can have a overview about the possible different properties..

Properties range, for example, from different `AiColor3D Colors` to several `int ShadingModels` or several `AiString Texture` types.. and so on

So basically with the `AiMaterialProperty` name we refer to a very different range of material properties..

And like this wasn't enough, each property may be an array of values, controlled by the `const unsigned int pNumValues` argument.

I alread wrote [something](https://github.com/elect86/jAssimp/blob/master/jAssimp/src/jassimp/components/material/AiMaterialProperty.java), but it is crap and I really don't like it. I just wrote it down what was my really first idea, that is essentially having a MaterialProperty that holds all the different types (String, int, float, etc) and only the relevant one will actually store the value of the given property..

Now I would like to improve it and I was thinking to have a base class `AiMaterialProperty` and then extend it based on the property type (`AiString`, `AiColor3D`, `int`, `boolean`, `float`, `AiVector3D`) such as `AiMaterialPropertyString`, etc..

Then I was planning to have a enum variable holding the `materialKey`, (everything that starts basically with `AI_MATKEY` in the [material.h](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/include/assimp/material.h)..

The problem is that some properties, like `SHADING_MODEL`, are enums on their turn... And since in Java enums cannot extend other enums I was kind of stuck..

So, I'd like to probe if anyone out there has a better idea regarding which structure would fit it at best for Java

Comment: I've just upvoted. I hate people who downvotes without explanation. Your post is detailed and well written, it doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: Welcome the club... Thanks gouessej!